# HTML/CSS image hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I want to create a simple image hover with `AboutUsLink.png` and `AboutUsColourLink.png` but I don't know how.

HTML:

```
<section class="link1">
    <a href="#SecondLink"><img src="images/LogoAndLinks/AboutUsLink.png"></a>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
.link1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 35%;
    margin-left: 22%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: this is very basic. please ask to google first

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS solution to this, set up your element like so:

```
<a href="#SecondLink"><div id="SecondLink"></div></a>
```

and then use the CSS to set the `div` background

```css
#SecondLink {
    background-image: url('images/LogoAndLinks/AboutUsLink.png');
}

#SecondLink:hover {
    background-image: url('images/LogoAndLinks/AboutUsColourLink.png');
}
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUbWJ/)

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work with my images but it works when I use let's say background-color:green;

Comment: oh, the quotes were missing from the image path...look at the edited answer

Comment: make sure you have the correct path to your image. The path will be relative to the file where you are using the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="link1">
  <a href="#SecondLink">
     <img src="images/LogoAndLinks/AboutUsLink.png" 
          onmouseover="this.src='images/LogoAndLinks/AboutUsColourLink.png';" 
          onmouseout="this.src='images/LogoAndLinks/AboutUsLink.png';" />
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: wouldn't recommend javascript in this instance.